# Контрол ComboBox, как выделить подстроку из Items курсивом или жирным?

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день.

На форме есть контрол ComboBox, нужно выделить подстроку из Items курсивом или жирным, как это сделать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `DrawMode` `ComboBox`'а установить в `OwnerDrawFixed`, то можно управлять отрисовкой каждого элемента списка. Делается это примерно так:

```
comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
comboBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(comboBox1_DrawItem);

private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {    
    Font font = comboBox1.Font;
    Brush brush = Brushes.Black;
    string text = comboBox1.Items[e.Index];

    if (/* этот элемент должен быть жирным */)
        font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Bold);

    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, brush, e.Bounds);
}
```

Событие `DrawItem` вызывается каждый раз при перерисовке любого `Item`'а из `comboBox1`. Ваша задача отследить нужный вам элемент и установить ему шрифт в жирный или курсив. Если хотите выделить подстроку, то нужно отрисовывать всю строку по частям: часть обычным, часть жирным.

**UPD**

Сделать элементы невыбираемыми можно так. Создаём класс, представляющий элемент списка, например, такой:

```
public class MyItem {
    public string Title { get; set; };
    public boolean IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public MyItem(string title) {
        this.Title = title;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return this.Title;
    }
}
```

Эти элементы добавляем в `ComboBox`. При отрисовке в `comboBox1_DrawItem` можно проверять, является ли этот элемент невыбираемым (`obj.IsEnabled == false`) и рисовать его на сером фоне. По событию `OnSelectedIndexChanged` проверяем, является ли новый выбранный элемент невыбираемым, и если да, то просто не меняем индекс выбранного элемента (для этого придётся запоминать индекс предыдущего выбранного элемента).

Comment: Спасибо. Небольшое уточнение: string text = comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();

Comment: Возникла проблема: http://i1.5cm.ru/i/JacH.png
Когда проводишь мышкой по остальным (не выделенным) итемам - вот такая аказия проявляется. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Поясните первый пункт, пожалуйста. По вашей картинке не совсем понятно, какая именно "аказия" у вас происходит.

Comment: Сравните шрифт "Запчасти и аксессуары=10" и "Коммерческая недвижимость=42". До провода мышкой по "Запчасти и аксессуары=10" шрифт был идентичен "Коммерческая недвижимость=42". Т.е. после провода мышкой шрифт "плывет".

Проверял на нескольких ПК, проблема не в системе.

Comment: Затрудняюсь сказать точно. Такое чувство, что вы перерисовываете несглаженным шрифтом. Точно сказать не могу.